# Where clause in select statement gives the same result for int or string is passed

Tags: mysql

Result for query

```
select * from job_master where job_id='7ss,dsd..'
```

and

```
select * from job_master where job_id=7
```

Resultset of query is the same and job_id is column with type BIGINT(10)

Comment: How is that possible ?

Comment: Please add the full source code you have and show us the two different ways how you set the `WHERE` condition and how you read the data.

Comment: MySQL will implicitly cast a string value to an integer to compare it to an integer column (job_id). If the string begins with one or more numbers, MySQL will use those numbers to cast it, and discard the rest of the non-numeric string. If it starts with a non-numeric character, it will cast as null.

Comment: There are a lot of related questions with complete answers. I'll find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's how MySQL works folks. MySQL tends to take numeric value first from the value you put in your where clause. In simple words, It scans the value in where clause. Once it finds any such value, it considers that value as the final one. For instance,

```
'abc' => MySQL would read it as 0
'1abc' => MySQL would read it as 1
'a1bc' => MySQL would read it as 0
```

You can try and come across some more new things in MySQL.